# what does "Left off" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Has anyone help me to understand meaning of "Left off" for example in below sentence:

> Where We Left Off and What’s Next

Comment: Please post a full sentence. The above is not a full sentence. Perhaps you meant http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leave+off

Also please visit http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not *left of*, but *left off* and means 'where we finished last time'.

Comment: so left off means finished last time Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Affable Geek gives a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Think of it as shorthand for "This is where we left and went off to do other things. When we return, we will pick up at this point. ". (And "pick it back up" is often used in conjunction with left off, as in "We'll pick back up where we left off tomorrow,")

In other words, it is a marker that indicates the point at which activity was paused, with the intent that activity will resume at that place later.

Comment: Why the downvote?